# Consistently very large bundle for vendor -- what should be done to reduce it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am bundling my vendor dependencies like so:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    vendor: [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'react-router',
      'velocity-react',
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: Infinity,
      filename: 'vendor.js',
    }),
  ]
}
```

Despite these few dependencies, webpack is consistently saying that my vendor chunk is large.

[image]

I am not so sure that this is being handled correctly -- is there a way to reduce this bundle's size? Should dependencies such as react be broken into their own separate chunk?

Comment: Run Uglify over it, and ignore the warning. Some apps need 300kb of javascript

Answer (score 1):

What we usually do is to mark the external libraries as "externals" in our webpack -  this keeps our core library independent of the third party dependencies. Here is an example : 
https://github.com/flexicious/react-redux-datagrid/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js

```
webpackConfig.externals = {
          "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
        "flexicious-react-datagrid":"flexiciousNmsp"
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about that, but it did noticeably decrease the bundle size from 312kb to 260kb

Comment: Great - just a quick note flexicious-react-datagrid is our react datagrid component - so you dont need that in your externals unless you are using it http://www.reactdatagrid.com/

Comment: This however simply moves the same weight into two different browser requests at runtime. The size is the same, and now you add the overhead of having 3 different requests: 1 for each script tag and 1 for your bundle.

Comment: @CharlieBrown - correct, however, this is useful in scenarios where multiple bundles refer to the same thirdparty library - which in our case is fairly common - React, ReactDOM etc. Plus it allows browsers to cache react independantly. Each scenario is different, so this may not be the best approach for every situation.

Comment: Absolutely @flexicious.com, you could achieve the same splitting your bundles and outputting a `vendor` bundle with all your dependencies. The op however was complaining about the bundle size by looking at the webpack output, when the concern should be over-the-wire transfer size. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should generate your bundles with minification enabled (basically running `webpack -p` for production).

In addition, you should set the global variable `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `production` so the dead code elimination works within the React module. See here:

http://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing-build/setting-environment-variables/#setting-process-env-node_env-

If you finally enable gzip compression on your webserver it should go much lower.

For example, see here the CDN version of the latest React, minified:

https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.2/dist/react.min.js
https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.4.2/dist/react-dom.min.js

Open your browser Dev tools, networks inspector, and see they are at around ~30Kb each (gzipped).

Comment: Done all of these things, unfortunately :\

Comment: But you're checking your bundle size, not the gzipped size your end users will really perceive. You could always use a CDN like the one provided and define React and ReactDOM as externals in webpack, so the user doesn't have to download those files from your server in case you can't gzip them.

Comment: On top of that, 300Kb doesn't look too much to me. Your images, icons or Google Fonts will be way heavier than that. :)